# Linux command to find Lowest value in a particular column of a data file

Tags: linux

I have a data file with three columns and I want to search the lowest value in the third column and print the corresponding values of column 1,2 and 3.
I want to do it using a linux terminal command. How should I do it ?
I tried grep command and cut -f1 -d"," contourRESFsi1.dat | sort -n | head -1 also, but it is not giving me the right values..

Thank you.

Comment: [mcve] please. Show your code, input and output.

Comment: ok... my input is like this - 0 90 0.3664 , 0 90 1.025, 0 90 12.03, 0 90 2.03.. and so on . 3 columns and say 300 rows. I want output as 0 90 0.3664 , corresponding row members of the lowest third column value. I have no code for it, I want to use a linux command from the terminal and want the output on the terminal itself...

Comment: Please put relevant stuff into the question, not into comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sort` do get the min of the third column:

```
sort -n -k 3 file.txt | head -n 1
```

- `-n` option is to sort by number (default is alpha)
- `-k` option is to specify which column to sort
- `-t` option is to specify the column separator (default is space or tab)

---

Explanation:

The command `sort` is sorting your file on the fly (putting the lowest number first, and the greatest at the end), thanks to the option `-n`.
Then, the `head` command takes the first line of that "on the fly, sorted buffer", hence producing only one line (the one with the lowest value).

To cut the three lowest values, for example:

```
sort -n -k 3 file.txt | head -n 3
```

Comment: Hi, on using this command,  output: sort: invalid option -- '3'

Comment: I tried this command , but the value that it is giving is not in my file....is it calculating something ?? Can I attach my data file so that you can also see?

Comment: @Srishino There's no attachement here, but you can copy/paste your file content on https://justpaste.it and put the link here.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/3gws9

Comment: yes Sir, correct. my mistake, I was running it on a different file. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Sir, can you explain me how does it work ?

Comment: Thank you Sir.. I understood it better now.